# Jenkins Declarative pipeline - Convert multi string data to xml

Tags: maven, jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I am new to the Jenkins pipeline. Can anyone help me with the following logic to convert string data to XML content in Jenkins declarative pipeline script.

```
pipeline{
        agent any
      parameters {
             text defaultValue:  '''host=localhost port=2222 url=http://localhost:2222''', description: 'api details', name : 'api'
         }
           stage('api details') {
            steps{ 
             script{
         def apiList= api.split("\n")
          
          for(String item :  apiList) {
    
             def resultList = item.split("=") as List
              println(resultList.size())
              
              for(String finalItem : resultList)
              {
                  println("<"+finalItem .getAt(0)+">"+finalItem .getAt(1)+"/<"+finalItem .getAt(0)+">")
              }
          }
    
              } 
           } 
       } 
    }
```

final Output:

```
<host>localhost</host>
<port>2222</port>
<url>http://localhost:2222</url>
```

Comment: The question has nothing related to Mule, removing the tag. Also you should ask each question separately. Otherwise the question may be closed because of lack of focus (multiple questions in one).

Answer (score 0):

Check the following code.

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    parameters {
             text defaultValue:  '''host=localhost port=2222 url=http://localhost:2222''', description: 'api details', name : 'api'
         }
    stages {
        stage('Hello') {
            steps {
                echo 'Hello World'
                script{
                    def apiList = api.split("\\s")
                    def xmlPart = ""
          
                     for(String item :  apiList) {
                         def parts = item.split("=")
                         println("<"+ parts[0] + ">" + parts[1] +"</" + parts[0] + ">")
                         xmlPart += "<"+ parts[0] + ">" + parts[1] +"</" + parts[0] + ">\n"
                    }
                    println xmlPart
              } 
            }
        }
    }
}
```